# Temporary Stripe subscription price

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I've been asked to integrate Stripe API's for a subscription plan.
I've already worked with it, but never with a variable price :
I have to make a subscription with a "trial price" and then, the month after, change the price.
Here, the user wil pay 19 euros the first month, and then 25 euros each month. But, I can't see any options to manage it ? 
Do you have a clue ?

Thanks !

Comment: You're probably looking for something like [this](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/discounts)

Answer (score 2):

Your best approach is to [discount](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/discounts) their first invoice.

> Coupons in Stripe provide discounts on recurring charges. Like subscriptions, coupons allow for great flexibility in how you define and use them. They can:
>
> - Apply to every invoice, **just one invoice**, or for a certain length of time

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#first-invoice-extra

> Should you need to include a one-time charge or discount to the first subscription invoice, you can do so by adding an invoice item to the customer before creating the subscription. (The above code would work, as it doesn’t specify an invoice.) The resulting invoice item will be attached to the customer and automatically included in the first invoice created.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer ! I'm checking it out !